# Render The Results from Two Mongo Queries on One Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've recently started playing around with MongoDB and Node.js/Express and I'm still having difficulties grasping some of the concepts.

Excuse the newbie question. I couldn't find an existing answer which covered what I'm trying to learn.

It's quite simple really, I just want to output the results from two separate mongo queries on a single page. I don't need to group or otherwise join the data in any way, I just need to display the results of each query on the one page.

So, I can query and display a single query no problem, but I fall down with the second query because the example code I have does the query in the .js file and renders the page and passes the result as an array (if I'm understanding properly) so

```
        var collection = db.collection('photographers');
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error retrieving records");
                res.send(err);
            }else if (result.length){
                console.log("Success");
                res.render('ptlist',{
                    "ptlist":result
                });
            }else{
                res.send('No Documents');
            }
            db.close();
```

renders my view 'ptlist' and passes the result in the array ptlist.

I can't work out how to then perform another query to a different collection and have the array of results also available to use in the view 'ptlist'.

An (simple) examples would be gratefully received. Otherwise pointers to where I might find some nicely commented examples would also be cool.

Sorry if this is a stupid question. It's still very early days for mew with this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the easiest solution, based on your code.

It's not great, there is a callback hell, but it will work, assuming that the `finalResult` has a structure which can be consumed by the view.

To make things nicer you could use `async` for example.
Or `co` and MongoDB ES6 `yield` as in [their sample code](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/ecmascript6/crud/).

```
var collection = db.collection('photographers');
collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
    var finalResult = {};
    if(err){
        console.log("Error retrieving records");
        res.send(err);
    } else if (result.length){
        console.log("Success");
        finalResult.plist = result;
        collection.find({/* another query */}).toArray(function(err,result){
            finalResult.anotherKey = result;
            res.render('ptlist',{
                "ptlist":finalResult
            });
        });
    }else{
        res.send('No Documents');
    }
    db.close();
});
```